# Import Excel file to pandas from Github repository

Tags: python, pandas, github, import

In my effort to export Excel file in my private Github repository to Pandas data frame using the source code below:

```
username= 'xxx'
token = 'yyyy'
github_session = requests.Session()
github_session.auth = (username, token)

url = 'correct path to raw file'
export = requests.get(url).content

df = pd.read_excel(io.StringIO(export.decode('utf-8')))
```

**I have encountered an error while running the last line of the above chunk:**

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'str' and 'int'
```

**The Excel raw data file from Github repository has combined numeric and string records.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel is a binary file format. Use `io.BytesIO(export)` instead

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 

```pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(export.decode('utf-8')))``` returns type error as follows: **TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'** 

when ```pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(export))``` returns the following error: **xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\n\n\n\n\n<!D'**

Comment: don't use `.decode`; decode converts it into a string format